# Apache POI: How to change the row which is displayed top-most in a viewer?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

According documentation, [`Sheet.getTopRow()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getTopRow()) returns *"The top row in the visible view when the sheet is first viewed after opening it in a viewer"*.

**How can I change this value?**

It seems that Apache POI sets the last row as the top-most row by default - I'd like to display the first row instead.

**UPDATE:**
I'm not sure whether this is important:
 I create a sheet which contains 100 rows.
I'm using a freeze pane to always display the first 4 rows - these are indeed shown top-most. The first row which is shown after the freeze pane is row 101 (which is empty - so nothing is displayed).
 
**I always need to scroll up to see any data**.

I'd like to ask for a way that row 5 is shown instead after the file has been opened in a viewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it with [createFreezePane](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#createFreezePane%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) with no split set. (That's just how Excel encodes it)

If you want Excel row 10 (= POI row 9, POI is 0-based), then you'd need to do

```
sheet.createFreezePane(0, 0, 0, 10-1);
```

If you want to freeze the first 4 rows, then have Excel row 10 (=POI 9) shown at the top of the bottom section, then it'd be:

```
sheet.createFreezePane(0, 4, 0, 10-1);
```

(More details are in the [createFreezePane JavaDocs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#createFreezePane%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29))

You should be able to check that it worked, by then fetching the top row

Comment: I'm already using a freeze pane in order to freeze the first 4 rows. These are displayed top-most. However, the next row which is shown is the row after the last row - so an empty sheet (beside the first rows of the freeze pane) is displayed.

Comment: What happens if you do `sheet.createFreezePane(0, 4, 0, 10-1)` - does that give you a 4 row freeze at the top and row 10 (POI 9) at the top of the bottom?

Comment: Thank you. I did not realize that the last parameter of createFreezePane() actually sets the top-most visible row. I set it to 100 which perfectly explains my problem. After setting it to 4 ( `sheet.createFreezePane(0, 4, 0, 4)` ) everything works like expected.

Comment: Aren't the javadocs clear enough on what that parameter does? If not, could you suggest some alternate text?

Comment: The javadocs are perfect. I just missed to read them carefully.